# Macbook Pro with OS X 10.8.4 will not connect to WiFi

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought my mac in india recently and i'm using it in UK. It worked fine for a month but now,  whenever i try to connect to the wifi, it says "connection timeout". There is no problem with the wifi because my family doesn't face any such problems on their laptops. I tried refreshing network preferences but didn't work. What do i have to do to make it connect?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what your current wireless network topology consists of? (i.e. What type of wireless router are you trying to connect to?, etc..)

Comment: @aakruti This article may be useful http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/osx/macbook-pro-constantly-dropping-wireless-connection/

Comment: I don't think that article has anything to do with the problem. As it describes constant dropouts, not connection timeouts which are different.

Answer (score 2):

Connection timeouts can be related to authentication issues sometimes. I recently answered a similar question regarding wifi problems that describes how to remove the network and password details.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100217/6529

I would suggest trying this to see if it is an authentication problem.